# Chromatic polynomial of a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

I have the following graph with $nm$ vertices:

```
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- (n)
|     |     |
4 --- 5 --- 6 --- (n)
|     |     |
7 --- 8 --- 9 --- (n)
|     |     | 
|     |     |
(m)   (m)   (m)
```

In other words, this is a graph of a grid with $m$ rows and $n$ columns.  How can I determine the chromatic polynomial of this graph?  Say, for $n=4$ and $m=4$? Is there a way to form a general formula for such a graph,?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do the $(n)$'s and $(m)$'s represent vertices?

Comment: @Casteels yes. It means that it can have n * m vertices. Basically its a grid.

Comment: Here's something to read: http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.6206

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Reading it now. Thanks. :)

Comment: Couldnt get much of it. :(

Comment: I derived an explicit polynomial for this problem. What do I do with this information?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an open problem by Read and Tutte .  You are essentially asking for the chromatic polynomial of the grid graph (the vertices of degree $1$ do not matter.)See the attached picture from  Read R.C. and W.T. Tutte. *Chromatic polynomials*. In: L.W. Beineke and R.J. Wilson, Selected Topics in Graph Theory, volume **3**, pages 15--42.

Also [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://math.nie.edu.sg/fmdong/talks/prob-chrom-Dec-2004-Xiamen.pdf&ei=OgtcUvFNxc_hBJjBgYgK&usg=AFQjCNE4aTNsSGe_pAolW0SYhpk2VK0P7A&sig2=feBHsJ7tCP8tbnJrKwguog&bvm=bv.53899372,d.bGE) are some slides from a not so old talk in which it was said that this is still open.

[image]

Comment: The picture in the post suggests that the solution for general $n$ and $m$ is not known. In particular, some well known mathematicians did not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Mathematica can compute chromatic polynomial for some graphs, as explained in [this web page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticPolynomial.html).

> The chromatic polynomial of a graph g in the variable z can be determined using `ChromaticPolynomial[g, z]` in the Mathematica package `Combinatorica` . Precomputed chromatic polynomials for many named graphs can be obtained using `GraphData[graph, "ChromaticPolynomial"][z]`.

Mathematica has precomputed polynomials for grid graphs up to $n<5$ & $m<5$.
I tried to compute `ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[3, 6], z]` but it didn't finished yet after an hour.

See also [this web page](http://oeis.org/wiki/Colorings_of_grid_graphs).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\chi_{m,n}(q)$ denote the chromatic polynomial of an $m\times n$ grid graph. An application of the transfer-matrix method shows that for fixed $m$, the generating function $\sum_{n\geq 1}\chi_{m,n}(q)x^n$ is a rational function of $q$ and $x$. For $m=3$ we get
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\chi_{3,n}(q)x^n = \frac{q(1-q)(1-q+(1-3q+q^2)x)x}
    {1+(10-11q+5q^2-q^3)x+(11-24q+19q^2-7q^3+q^4)x^2}. $$
It is also easy to see directly that
$$ \chi_{2,n}(q) = q(q-1)(q^2-3q+3)^{n-1}. $$