# Number of ways to color a grid?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I have a $N \times M $ grid and I am trying to calculate the number of ways I can color this grid in maximum $k$ colors (I can use only $2$ colors or all $k$ colors) with the exception that two adjacent cells can not be painted in the same color.

For example the following 3x3 grid can be colored in colors {0, 1, 2} in this way:

```
(2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 0)
```

but not in this way:

```
(2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 1, 1)
```

because two colors 1 are adjacent (in the last row).

---

Currently I am out of ideas how to approach it.

**I tried to use inclusion-exclusion** principle where I counted all ways to count the colors, then removing all where 2 colors are adjacent and so on. Not only I was not able to calculate it properly I am also am not sure that this is correct.

**I also tried to use the following approach.** The `(0, 0)` cell can be colored in $k$ ways. The `(0, 1)` can be colored in $k-1$ way (the same way `(0, 2)` ... and all other in this row.

On the next row `(1, 0)` can be also colored in $k - 1$ way. But the `(1, 1)` element can be colored in $k-1$ way if cells `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` are colored in the same way and in $k-2$ ways otherwise. This looked like a valid approach, but I still can not figure out how to calculate it.

Am I on the right track with my second approach or there is a better way to calculate this?

Comment: I think this might be an open problem in graph theory.  See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642921/chromatic-polynomial-of-a-grid-graph).

Comment: @augurar really thank you. Did not know about it. Does this mean that there is absolutely no better known way to count it except of a brute-force?