# Find the chromatic polynomial of the $3 \times 3$ grid graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Find the chromatic polynomial of the $3 \times 3$ grid graph.

[image]

Maple give the answer 
$$
\lambda\, \left( \lambda-1 \right)  \left( {\lambda}^{7}-11\,{\lambda}
^{6}+55\,{\lambda}^{5}-161\,{\lambda}^{4}+298\,{\lambda}^{3}-350\,{
\lambda}^{2}+244\,\lambda-79 \right),
$$
but I want  to do it by hand.

I have tried to apply the deletion-contraction but without any success.

**Edited.**  I can find the chromatic polynomial for such graph:

[image]

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/642921/19341

Comment: maybe but there asked about the  hardest  case $4 \times 4$

Comment: Deletion-contraction ought to work. Why not show how far you got with it, and we'll see if we can't help you along.

Comment: I can do it by deletion-contraction  only  for the graph when we delete  the (3,3) vertice  from the grid graph. I cant do the last step

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your comment. What do you mean by "the last step"?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  See correction of my post

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "the last step". What goes wrong when you use the same techniques on the graph you can't do as you use on the graph you can do?

Comment: the  "last step" means moving from the second graph  ( I can do it )  to the first  one( I cant do it).

Comment: I don't see how "moving" from one graph to another, more complicated, graph is a "step" in find the polynomial for the more complicated graph. So I can only speak in generalities: deletion-contraction replaces a graph with two graphs, one of which has fewer edges than the original, the other has fewer edges and fewer vertices. Carried out repeatedly, it will reduce any graph to a collection of graphs with no edges and complete graphs, and then it's easy to find the polynomials for those. Doing this by hand for even moderate sized graphs can be extremely tedious. What more can I say?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,  yes, you are right, I was stupid  but now I have calculated it. Thank you!