# Ways of coloring an NxNxN cube

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have an NxNxN cube made of N$^3$ smaller cubes, and each small 1x1x1 cube is painted some color (1 of K colors).

My question is, how many ways can I color the cube so that no adjacent cubes are the same color?

For this purpose, I can think of multiple reasonable definitions of "adjacent", and would be interested in any and all of the definitions applied here:

1. Adjacency means sharing a face, but cubes that are diagonal (sharing just a corner), or sharing only 1 edge, can be the same color.
2. Adjacency means diagonal cubes (those that share a corner only)
3. Adjacency means cubes sharing a single edge only
4. Any combination of the 3 definitions above

Comment: So you have $2^3=8$ different problems (different notions of adjaceny) that you want solved for all values of $N$? I guess I'll pass. But I'll mention that [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) might be a useful keyword. Oh, wait a minute. Do you count two colorings as different if they differ only by a rotation or reflection of the big cube? If not, [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) might be another useful keyword.

Comment: You're right, I guess I should have been more specific because maybe more appropriately there are only 7 problems (ignoring the case of adjacency not including any of the 3 conditions) but really I'd be happy with a solution to just one of the problems, I was just trying to delineate possible answers. Thanks for the keywords. For now, to make it easier, lets just say reflections and rotations can be counted as different ways.

Comment: If adjacency means sharing a face, then your graph is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of three paths: $G=P_N\square P_N\square P_N,$ and you want the [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) $P(G,k).$ For $N=1$ the number of colorings is $K;$ for $N=2$ according to [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticPolynomial.html) the number of colorings is $$K^8-12K^7+66K^6-214K^5+441K^4-572K^3+423K^2-133K.$$

Comment: In the case of facial adjacency (with rotations and reflections not allowed) you're asking for the chromatic polynomial of a three-dimensional grid graph. According to the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642921/chromatic-polynomial-of-a-grid-graph), the same problem for a two-dimensional grid is an old unsolved problem.